# How does one transform a nested object's hierarchy into a flat representation of itself with each flattened key reflecting its original property path?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, data-structures, reduce

I have a JSON conform object structure like this ...

```
{
  "Name": "Pedro Smith",
  "Age": "8",
  "Parents": {
    "Mother": {
      "Name": "Maria Smith",
      "RG": "123456"
    },
    "Father": {
      "Name": "Jose Smith",
      "RG": "5431"
    }
  }
}
```

... and I want to process the above object into a flat representation of itself. The new object should not be nested but its former hierarchy should be reflected by its key/property names where each new key was aggregated by its deepest value's property path.

The expected structure of the above given example should look like this ...

```
{
  "Name": "Pedro Smith",
  "Age": "8",
  "Parents-Mother-Name": "Maria Smith",
  "Parents-Mother-RG": "123456",
  "Parents-Father-Name": "Jose Smith",
  "Parents-Father-RG": "5431"
}
```

How can such a transformation task be achieved in JavaScript?

Comment: Those are JavaScript objects, not "JSON objects", which don't really exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

- The final, recursion based, approach is presented with the last example.
- Since the OP seems to be new to the matter, there will be 3 code iteration steps, each with explanations and documentation links, towards the final solution.

If one starts thinking about a solution for a non nested object structure or how to retrieve the object's first level *`key`-`value` pairs* (aka [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) one might think, that iterating over such *entries* and somehow executing a logging [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) *key-value pair* might be a valid first step/approach.

And since one does not want to use something like [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) but something more readable, an example code might end up looking like this ...

```js
const sample = {
  Name: "Pedro Smith",
  Age: "8",
  Parents: {
    Mother: {
      Name: "Maria Smith",
      RG: "123456",
    },
    Father: {
      Name: "Jose Smith",
      RG: "5431",
    },
  },
};

Object
  .entries(sample)
  .forEach(entry => {

    const key = entry[0];
    const value = entry[1];

    console.log(key + ': ' + value + '\n');
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Of cause one can improve the above code by not logging every iteration step but by aggregating the final result, which could be achieved with e.g. the help of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and some [*Destructuring assignments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) ...

```js
const sample = {
  Name: "Pedro Smith",
  Age: "8",
  Parents: {
    Mother: {
      Name: "Maria Smith",
      RG: "123456",
    },
    Father: {
      Name: "Jose Smith",
      RG: "5431",
    },
  },
};

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(sample)
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => [

      result,
      key + ': ' + value,
    
    ].join('\n'), '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

But the OP wants both a flattened object structure and aggregated keys, where the latter is supposed to somehow reflect the key path into each similar formed substructure. Thus, one needs to walk the object tree/structure.

In order to do so, and since the above example already offers a solution for a simple object branch, one needs to turn the `reduce` function into a [*recursive*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#recursion) one.

[The aggregating/accumulating first argument of `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works) will be used for collecting and configuration purposes like not just carrying the `result` reference but also referring to the current's key (aggregated by a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) `prefix` and the `connector` string ...

```js
function recursivelyConcatKeyAndAssignFlatEntry(collector, [key, value]) {
  const { connector, keyPath, result } = collector;

  // concatenate/aggregate the current
  // but flattened key if necessary.
  key = keyPath
    ? `${ keyPath }${ connector }${ key }`
    : key;

  if (value && (typeof value === 'object')) {
    // ... recursively continue flattening in case
    // the current `value` is an "object" type ...
    Object
      .entries(value)
      .reduce(recursivelyConcatKeyAndAssignFlatEntry, {
        connector,
        keyPath: key,
        result,
      });
  } else {
    // ... otherwise ... just assign a new flattened
    // key and current value pair to the final object.
    result[key] = value;
  }
  return collector;
}

const sample = {
  Name: "Pedro Smith",
  Age: "8",
  Parents: {
    Mother: {
      Name: "Maria Smith",
      RG: "123456",
    },
    Father: {
      Name: "Jose Smith",
      RG: "5431",
    },
  },
};

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(sample)
    .reduce(recursivelyConcatKeyAndAssignFlatEntry, {

      connector: '-',
      keyPath: '',
      result: {},

    }).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: +1 nice approach using recursion and modern JS, I provided similar approach but using simple `for..in`  and of course recursion.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem we will follow the approach of recursion:

1. Loop through object by looping all of the key/value pairs in our object `oldObject` with `for..in`.
2. Check if those values are also an object with operator `typeof` equal to object If yes, Again we will loop through the key/value pairs in that object but with recursion by calling the same function again `flattenObject`.
3. Until we have pulled out all of our nested keys concatenated with `-`, With their corresponding values and assigned them to our returned object `flattenedObject`.
4. Else in case the value of key `innerObj` is not an object, Just store it with its value in result object `flattenedObject` directly.

```js
const flattenObject = (oldObject) =>{
    
    const flattenedObject  = {};

    for (const innerObj in oldObject) {

        if ((typeof oldObject[innerObj]) === 'object') {
                const newObject = flattenObject(oldObject[innerObj]);
                for (const key in newObject) {
                    flattenedObject[innerObj + '-' + key] = newObject[key];
                }
            }
        else {
            flattenedObject[innerObj] = oldObject[innerObj];
        }
    }
    return flattenedObject;
};
```

*Test:*

```
const obj = {
  "Name": "Pedro Smith",
  "Age": "8",
  "Parents": {
    "Mother": {
      "Name": "Maria Smith",
      "RG": "123456"
    },
    "Father": {
      "Name": "Jose Smith",
      "RG": "5431"
    }
  }
}
console.log(flattenObject(obj));
```

*Result:*

```js
{
    "Name": "Pedro Smith",
    "Age": "8",
    "Parents-Mother-Name": "Maria Smith",
    "Parents-Mother-RG": "123456",
    "Parents-Father-Name": "Jose Smith",
    "Parents-Father-RG": "5431"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this question got brought back up recently, here's what I think of as a slightly simpler approach built atop a reusable [`pathEntries`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries) function:

```js
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (
          ([p, v]) => [[Array .isArray (obj) ? Number (k) : k, ... p], v]
        )
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]

const transform = (o) =>
  pathEntries (o) 
    .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k .join ('-')] = v), a), {})

const person = {Name: "Pedro Smith", Age: "8", Parents: {Mother: {Name: "Maria Smith", RG: "123456"}, Father: {Name: "Jose Smith", RG: "5431"}}}

console .log (transform (person))
```

`pathEntries` converts the input to this flexible format:

```js
[
  [["Name"], "Pedro Smith"], 
  [["Age"], "8"], 
  [["Parents", "Mother", "Name"], "Maria Smith"], 
  [["Parents", "Mother", "RG"], "123456"], 
  [["Parents", "Father", "Name"], "Jose Smith"], 
  [["Parents", "Father", "RG"], "5431"]
]
```

`transform` calls `pathEntries` and then then folds the result into a single object by joining the paths with `'-'`.

A suggestion, though, is that you might want to look for another separator than `'-'`.  A lot of people use `'.'` and I've also seen `'|'`.  The problem is the ambiguity if you wanted to add a property like `'Mother-In-Law'`.  Does `'Parents-Mother-In-Law-Name': 'Clara Petrie'` suggest

```js
{
  // ...
  Parents: {
    // Mother, Father
    'Mother-In-Law': {Name: 'Clara Petrie'}
    //
  }
}
```

or does it mix into `'Mother'` like this:

```js
{
  // ...
  Parents: {
    Mother {
      Name: 'Marie Smith',
      RG: '123456',
      In: {
        Law: {
          Name: 'Clara Petrie'
        }
      }
    // Father
  }
}
```

?  There is no perfect separator, but the hyphen offers more likely ambiguities.